# Why doesn't the address bar show after exiting fullscreen mode?

Tags: javascript, samsung-mobile, mobile-phones

After exiting fullscreen on mobile Galaxy A51 (and couple of other devices as well) address bar is not shown. The status bar does appear.

```
function toggleFullscreen(event) {
var element = document.documentElement;
  if (event instanceof HTMLElement) {
    element = event;
}
  var isFullscreen = document.webkitIsFullScreen || document.mozFullScreen || false;

  element.requestFullScreen = element.requestFullScreen || element.webkitRequestFullScreen || element.mozRequestFullScreen || function () {
    return false;
};
  document.cancelFullScreen = document.cancelFullScreen || document.webkitCancelFullScreen || document.mozCancelFullScreen || function () {
return false;
};
  isFullscreen ? document.cancelFullScreen() : element.requestFullScreen();
}
```

I've tried

```
window.scrollTo(0,0);
```

but it did not help. Any ideas how to fix this?

So I found out if I go full screen and then change phone orientation to landscape and then back to portrait - address bar appears.